# How to render image caption to lightbox caption using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

I've caption under every image

```
<p>
<a href="large.jpg"> 
<img width="85" height="75" src="thumb.jpg/>
</a>Caption</p>
```

I want to render same caption at bottom of lightbox.

```
<span id="lightbox-image-details-caption">...Here.......</span>
```

How to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal way is too include a title attribute in your link;

```
<p>
<a href="large.jpg" title="Your Caption"> 
<img width="85" height="75" src="thumb.jpg" />
</a>
</p>
```

This title will be published in `<span id="lightbox-image-details-caption"></span>`
Will this work for you or do you need to add the text after the image as you've done now?

Comment: Hi Tim I want to with my example. I can't add title. because I'm working on a big image gallery. So to save time javascript solution like i want would be better

Comment: hmm that's hard... lightbox doesn't support a callback function to code after your image is shown. I advice to add the title, even for a big gallery this will work and it's neat coding. maybe you can add a piece of jquery what onload will set the caption to the title of the element?

Comment: OK than I'm going to do that way.